# Azure DevOps AzureCLI@2 create linux webapp

Tags: azure-devops, azure-cli

I'm trying to create some resources using the `AzureCLI@2` pipeline task. I'm creating a resource group, followed by a linux app service plan then trying to create a webapp that uses the app service plan. This is my task...

```
  - task: AzureCLI@2
    displayName: Create resources
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: ${{parameters.serviceConnectionName}}
      scriptType: ps
      scriptLocation: inlineScript
      inlineScript: | #I cannot get a linux webapp to work! ARGHHHH!
        az group create --location ${{parameters.location}} --name $(resourceGroup)
        az configure --defaults group=$(resourceGroup) location=${{parameters.location}}

        az appservice plan create -n $(appServicePlan) --sku ${{parameters.appPlanSku}} --is-linux

        az webapp create --name $(AppServiceName) --plan $(appServicePlan) --runtime --% "DOTNETCORE|5.0"
```

This is the error I receive:

```
ERROR: Linux Runtime 'DOTNETCORE|5.0' is not supported. Please invoke 'az webapp list-runtimes --linux' to cross check
```

running `az webapp list-runtimes --linux` gives me

```
az webapp list-runtimes --linux
[
  "RUBY|2.5.5",
  "RUBY|2.6.2",
  "NODE|14-lts",
  "NODE|12-lts",
  "NODE|10-lts",
  "NODE|10.1",
  "NODE|10.10",
  "NODE|10.12",
  "NODE|10.14",
  "NODE|12.9",
  "PHP|7.2",
  "PHP|7.3",
  "PHP|7.4",
  "DOTNETCORE|2.1",
  "DOTNETCORE|3.1",
  "DOTNETCORE|5.0",
  "TOMCAT|8.5-jre8",
  "TOMCAT|9.0-jre8",
  "JAVA|8-jre8",
  "WILDFLY|14-jre8",
  "JBOSSEAP|7-java8",
  "TOMCAT|8.5-java11",
  "TOMCAT|9.0-java11",
  "JAVA|11-java11",
  "JBOSSEAP|7-java11",
  "PYTHON|3.8",
  "PYTHON|3.7",
  "PYTHON|3.6",
  "STATICSITE|1.0"
]
```

Whats more frustrating is that this works if I use the Azure CLI locally.

The build agent is a self host windows agent running the latest version of the Azure CLI (upgraded to make sure that wasn't the issue).

Will switch to a windows app service plan for now as I've wasted so much time on this already. Has anybody got any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested and found it was the Azure CLI version that caused above issue.

I tested with the latest Azure cli version `2.21.0` and `2.20.0`. They both failed with above error `Linux Runtime 'DOTNETCORE|5.0' is not supported`.

However, i can run above commands successfully with Azure CLI `2.8.0`

You can try downgrading the azure cli version to `2.8.0` in your self host windows agent.

If you want to use cloud hosted agents. You can run below commands to downgrade the azure cli version on the cloud agent using a powershell task.

```
steps:
- powershell: |
   choco uninstall azure-cli --version=2.20.0  --force
   choco install azure-cli --version=2.8.0 --force

- task: AzureCLI@2
```

You can aslo using [azure powershell commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.websites/new-azwebapp?view=azps-5.7.0) to create webapp. See [this example](https://thegreenerman.medium.com/create-an-appservice-with-azure-powershell-27c3823702ec).

Comment: ah, its working locally because I'm still using version 2.2.0! I'll not upgrade locally until this is fixed. Do I need to log a bug on github for this issue?

Comment: @Phil You can log a bug on github. Hopefully the development team can fix it soon.